# kotlin-compiler-embeddable missing within gradle build

Tags: kotlin, gradle

I am trying to setup a multiproject gradle/kotlin build and I am getting following error:

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':compileKotlin'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':kotlinCompilerClasspath'.
   > Cannot resolve external dependency org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler-embeddable:1.4.10 because no repositories are defined.
     Required by:
         project :
```

Strange thing is the empty `project :`.

My simplifiged `build.gradle.kts` looks like this:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    base
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.4.10"
}

buildscript {
    extra["kotlin_version"] = "1.4.10"

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

subprojects {
    apply(plugin = "kotlin")

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    tasks.compileKotlin {
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "11"
    }

    tasks.compileTestKotlin {
        kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "11"
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:${rootProject.extra["kotlin_version"]}")
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:${rootProject.extra["kotlin_version"]}")
    }
}
```

Do I need to duplicate the repositories within the `buildscript` section?

What is that is causing the error above?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [kotlin + gradle+ intellij - no repositories are defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60610589/kotlin-gradle-intellij-no-repositories-are-defined)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like your `repositories { ... }` configuration done in the `subproject` section is sufficient, but it is only applied to the supbrojects but not the root project itself (which has the Kotlin plugin applied, too, and whose task `:compileKotlin` is failing).

There are two ways to fix this.

First, you could move the `repositories { ... }` section from `subprojects { ... }` to a new block `allprojects { ... }` (thus applied to the root project as well).

Or, if you don't actually need the Kotlin plugin in the root project (i.e. you don't have Kotlin code there), you can [add `.apply(false)`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:subprojects_plugins_dsl) to your plugin declaration:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm").version("1.4.10").apply(false)
}
```